# SumoLogic query: Search pattern is not in log

Tags: sumologic

I've been trying to search logs in Sumo that do not contain a pattern like this one: `"id=a*"`. This looks pretty simple but I have several attempts and nothing yet.

Tried doing `... and not "id=a"`: This doesn't work because this never is the case, logs come like id=a123 for example.

Also with `... and not "id=a*"`: here Sumo doesn't use `*` as a wildcard so it doesn't work either.

Tried with `... and not id=a*"` This one doesn't work at all, because = needs to be escaped.

Tried with: `... and not id%"="a*` this one doesn't yield the correct results. TheI grabbed %"=" from https://help.sumologic.com/05Search/Get-Started-with-Search/Search-Basics/Reference_a_Field_with_Special_Characters

I just want to make sure something like this gets selected: id=a123 but not something like this id=z123.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with:

```
....
| parse "id=*}" as id
| where id matches /^(?!a).+/
```

By doing this we isolate blabla from id=blabla} and then with regex just check that the string doesn't start with a.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I ran into the same issue so I want to post this here.

```
_collector="someCollector"
NOT "id=z"
NOT "id=x"
parse "id=*"
//should return all ids NOT z or x
```

Hope this helps someone :)